# How to detect Python datetime format strings that contain multiple format codes for the same component (month, day, etc.)?

Tags: python, datetime

`datetime.datetime.strptime` allows formats like `"%b %m"`:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('Oct 5', '%b %m')
datetime.datetime(1900, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```

While technically valid, this is confusing behavior and can cause bugs. Especially in a use case where datetime formats are configured dynamically and often.

What would be the easiest way to detect something like this? My idea would be to group codes by "component" like `{'month': ('%b', '%m', '%-m', ...), ...}` and ensure a given format string only contains one code from each group.

While this would work, it feels a bit clunky. Is there a more canonical approach?

Comment: In your example, the input would be equally ambiguous, no? Why would you supply the same quantity (month in this case) *twice* ? The other way around, if you configure the parsing directive dynamically, the algorithm that does this should not allow to contain the same quantity twice. For instance, a string like 'Oct 5' should give something like '%b %d'.